# How to modify flexbox so that one element fills up whole row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to make a progress bar (for music playback), but when width of the #progress bar is 100%, it doesn't fill up the whole container .progress-bar (as seen in photo)(Light grey part depicts whole duration).  I assume this is due to flexbox, as the dot fills up part of the space, but don't know a workaround for this so that the dot stays at the end of #progress.

```css
.progress-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#progress {
  background-color: #535353;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#progress-dot {
  position: relative;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  transform: translate(-12.5px, -7px);
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div id="progress"></div>
  <div id="progress-dot"></div>
</div>
```

**IMAGE**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olub3.png

Comment: Your transform on the dot is moving it to the left

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm seeing a little bit of progress bar sticking out at the end in your codepen as well? @Pricyquint The culprit is the `transform`, which moves it back by `12.5px`, the exact bit sticking out. Turn it into `translate(0,-7px)` and the dot is aligned with the right.

Comment: @j08691 Yes but this just aligns the dot with the end of the line.  If I get rid of the transform there is quite a clear gap between the line and the dot.  Even if I move the dot away, the width of the inner progress bar doesn't reach the end

Comment: @somethinghere Sorry if I didn't make it clear the light grey part is the background of the progress bar (i.e shows the song duration left).  When I do your translate there is quite a visible gap between the dot and the progress line, which is why I translated it.

Comment: Please make clearer what problem you are trying to solve, as I'm inclining to agree with @Paulie_D - cannot replicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the thumb is inside of the progress container and hence space must be allowed for it in a flex container.

The `transform` is purely visual and does not affect actual layout.

I'd suggest "removing" it from the flow by positioning it absolutely.

```css
.progress-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#progress {
  background-color: #535353;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* equivalent to value */
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#progress-dot {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  /* equivalent to value */
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -7px);
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: .25;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div id="progress"></div>
  <div id="progress-dot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only problem is that the dot's position no longer dynamically adjusts as the width of #progress is varied.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: The `left` value will always be the same as the width of the bar.... see the code comment. Or use a CSS variable - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yLropqO

Comment: Sorry I'm dumb, makes perfect sense, I'm very new to web dev. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can position the components absolutely. You can also do this with just one element. Note that I've used a variable (custom property) to avoid value repetition.

```css
:root {
  --progress-dot-size: 25px;
  --progress-value: 75%;
}

.progress-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.progress-bar::before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #535353;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: var(--progress-value);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.progress-bar::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: var(--progress-value);
  transform: translateX(calc(0px - var(--progress-dot-size) / 2));
  height: var(--progress-dot-size);
  width: var(--progress-dot-size);
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
```